# The path of a URI with an authority must start with a slash "/" or be empty. DigitalOcean Spaces AWS S3 SDK PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, digital-ocean-spaces

```
System error occurred

The path of a URI with an authority must start with a slash "/" or be empty.
Automagically fixing the URI by adding a leading slash to the path is 
deprecated since version 1.4 and will throw an exception instead.
line#755 file: /home/mySite/www/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Uri.php

PHP version: 7.4.14

Error executing "PutObject" on "//mySite.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/mySite.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com"; 
AWS HTTP error: 
Server error: 
PUT http://mySite.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/mySite.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com
resulted in a `501 Not Implemented` response:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
<Code>NotImplemented</Code>
<RequestId>tx00000000000000c12754f-0060564e57-96 (truncated...)
 NotImplemented (server): 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
  <Code>NotImplemented</Code>
  <RequestId>tx00000000000000c12754f-0060564e57-9617be5-nyc3c</RequestId
  <HostId>9617be5-nyc3c-nyc3-zg03</HostId>
</Error>"
```

I don't fully understand this error, I have tried changing the header request, I don't know what else to try, I am blank at the moment. I have also assumed it is a problem in the headers. Currently my header request looks like this:

```
:authority: mySite.com
:method: POST
:path: /request.ajax.php
:scheme: https
```

I will also leave the respective php codes:

```
function __construct($key, $secret_key, $space)
{
       $this->space = $space;

       try {
            $this->client = new \Aws\S3\S3Client([
                'version'  => 'latest',
                'region'   => 'us-east-1',
                'endpoint' => 'nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com',
                'credentials' => [
                    'key'    => $key,
                    'secret' => $secret_key
                ],
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
}

public _upload($path, $resource, $ctype)
{
        try {
            $this->client->putObject(array(
                'Bucket' => $this->space,
                'Key'    => $path,
                'Body'   => $resource,
                'ACL'    => 'public-read',
                'ContentType' => $ctype
            ));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

        return array("status" => "Success.");
}
```

part where I manage the file for the upload:

```
$path = "test/".basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$ctype = mime_content_type($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$stream = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r+');
$out = $xspaces->_upload($path, $stream, $ctype);
fclose($stream);
```

Comment: What is `$space` value passed to initialize the `$xspace` object?

Comment: The value I use is a text string, it is the digitalocean space or bucket to store the content.

Comment: I think it is trying to tell you that `$path` needs to start with a leading slash …? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-GuzzleHttp.Psr7.Uri.html#___toString

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `"/test/" . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);` I recently tried it but I still got the same error, I've tested my code (without the slash) in localhost and works as expected but when I try using it in my server it's not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After follow [this article](https://medium.com/light-it/digital-ocean-spaces-with-laravel-ddddf81a32cb), I Have same issue just change your .env and add protocol to **endpoint**

without protocol i got same error **(wrong)**
DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT=sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com

fix just add protocal to do_space **(correct)**
DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT=https://sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com